# Insert a record into table in ms access

Tags: forms, ms-access-2007

I need to create a small "application" using ms access 2007. All I need is to create a form that will take care of input/output related to a few db tables. 
I created the tables: patients, treatments and labresults.

Primary key in patients table is ID, and it serves as a foreign key in treatments and labresults tables, where it is named patientID.

I also created a form that I mentioned in the beginning of this question. It has multiple tabs. 1st tab opens/creates the patient, and the second one is used to enter data that is to be entered into the labresults table. Same applies to treatments table.

My problem: `I added a button to the 2nd tab, and I want to attach an 'action' that will set an INSERT query with values taken from fields (controls) in tab 2, together with ID field taken from tab1 (that corresponds with patient ID from patients table), and then execute a query.`

Right now I'm trying to achieve this myself, but with little success. Also, searchin MS site for solution(s) is kind of hard, since it always show results that have 'query' in it :)... And query isn't smt I want to use. (However, I'll accept any solution).

Thx

Tables:

**patients**

```
ID - primary key, autogenerated
patientID - internal number of the patient record. I could've used this, but it would complicate my life later on :)
gender
age
dateOfDiagnose
```

- field names are actually in Serbian, but field names aren't that much important

**labtests**

```
ID - primary key
patientID - foreign key, from patients table
... bunch of numerical data :)
```

There are 2 more tables, but they basically reflect some additional info and are not as important.

My form needs to enable user to enter data about the patient, and then enter several rows in labtests table, as treatment progresses. There are 2 types of treatment, and there is a table related to that, but they only have few fields in it, containint info about the start of the treatment, and the rest is info about lab tests.

Comment: Please post labtest table schema. Have you read about relational databases? For example http://r937.com/relational.html.

Comment: yes ... well, my problem is ms access. i wanted to make it in php/mysql, but they insisted on access. i'm troubled by access part, not rdbms part :)

Comment: What do you intend to add to the lab table using this button? Can you write out some pseudo code?

Comment: when new patient record is created, i need a record containing initial lab results... 
there are two different treatments, each having several records in labresults table...
so, when I create a 1st treatment record in treatments table, i need 3 lab results, and then for the 2nd treatment few more lab results records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite possible to run SQL under VBA, but I suspect that it may be easier to simply set up the form properly. For example, if you set up the ID as the Link Child & Master fields for the lab results subform (which I hope you are using), then it will be filled in automatically. Furthermore, it is also possible to set the default value of a control to the value that was previously entered with very little code. I therefore suggest that you add some notes on what you wish to achieve.

**Some further notes based on subsequent comment**

From your comments, it appears that you have a minimum of three relevant tables:

**Patients**

```
PatientID PK, Counter
```

**Treatments**

```
TreatmentID PK, Counter
PatientID FK
TreatmentTypeID FK
```

**LabResults**

```
LabResultID PK, Counter
TreatmentID FK 
PatientID FK <-- Optional, can be got through TreatmentID
LabResultTypeID FK
```

In addition, you will need a TreatmentTypes table that list the two current treatments and allows for further treatment types:

**TreatmentTypes**

```
TreatmentTypeID PK, Counter 
TreatmentDescription
```

You will also need:

**LabResultTypes**

```
LabResultTypeID PK, Counter <-- This can be referenced in the LabResults table
TreatmentTypeID FK
```

There are arguments for PKs other than those suggested, in that you have natural keys, but I think it is easier when working with Access to use autonumbers, however, you will need indexes for the natural keys.

I strongly recommend that all tables also include date created, date modified/updated and a user ID for both. Access does not keep this data, you must do it yourself. Date created can be set by a default value, and if you are using the 2010 version, the other fields can have 'triggers' (data-level macros), otherwise, you will need code, but it is not too difficult. Note also that these same 'triggers' could be used to insert relevant records : [Meet the Access 2010 macro designer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100819045348/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/access/archive/2009/07/28/meet-the-access-2010-macro-designer.aspx).

Your form will contain records for each patient and two subforms, Treatments and LabResults. The Treatments subform is bound to the Treatments table having PatientID for LinkChild and Master fields and a combobox for TreatmentTypeID:

```
Rowsource: SELECT TreatmentTypeID, TreatmentDescription FROM TreatmentTypes
ColumnCount: 2
BoundColumn: 1
```

After a treatment type is added to the Treatments subform, you can run a query, or run SQL under VBA. You can either use the After Insert event for the form contained by the treatments subform or a button, the After Insert event has advantages, but it is only triggered when the user saves the record or moves from the record, which is the same thing. Working from the treatments subform, and the After Insert event, the SQL would be on the lines of:

```
''Reference Microsoft DAO x.x Object Library
Set db = CurrentDB
sSQL = "INSERT INTO LabResults (TreatmentID, PatientID, LabResultTypeID) " _
     & "SELECT " _
     & Me.TreatmentID & ", " _
     & Me.PatientID & ", " _
     & "LabResultTypeID FROM LabResultTypes " _
     & "WHERE TreatmentTypeID " = & Me.TreatmentTypeID
db.Execute sSQL

MsgBox "Records inserted: " & db.RecordsAffected

Me.Parent.LabResults_Subform.Form.Requery
```

The query should also include the date and username, as suggested above, if your version is less than 2010 and you have not set up triggers.

You will be tempted to use datasheets, I suspect, for the subforms. I suggest you resist the temptation and use either single forms of continuous forms, they are more powerful. For an interesting approach, you may wish to look at the Northwind sample database Customer Orders form.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to create a form that will enable user to enter some basic info about a patient, stored in patient table, and enter lab results information for different stages of patient' treatment. I know all of those stages, and I want to have all that information in one form, each available via tabs.

Comment: It seems that when you are creating a patient entry, a number of items should be appended to a patient_stage table. This is most easily done with a stages table, a patient table, and a conjunction table (patient_stages) that holds the patient id, the stage id or name and other relevat fields, such as dates. When the patient is created, you can run a query that appends records from the stage table to the patient_stage table. Is this the direction you imagined?

Comment: Hm, I'm not 100% clear on the stages table... Project request is quite complicated, and it was defined (unfortunately) by medical personnel at medical university :). I need the data for my MSc thesis (and I'm Comp. Sci. major, and also in trouble :) ). I'm trying to do with linked forms now. I'll modify the question to make things a little bit more clear, and would appreciate your opinion, if you'd like to further help :)

Comment: Wow... Thank you very much for this. I have to admit that I don't understand all of it (part about labResultTypes, which I didn't include in the db. the rest is basically the same, except that I manually enter treatment types. i'm positive that i won't come back to this, once db is filled with information). I'm also using access 2007, so I guess I'll need to use code. 
why do you recommend using dates?

Comment: Because you will not know you need dates until you need them and by then it is far too late.