# MS Access 2007: unable to change fields after "code opening" a form

Tags: forms, ms-access-2007

I'm fighting with creation of several forms in MS Access 2007. 
I accomplished the following: I have *patients* form, where I can create / edit patient records. When *save* button is pressed, I'm opening another form, that has a task of entering information that belong to 2 tables. Tables on that form are in 1-1 relationship, and both use foreign key (patiendID from patients table).

I managed to make everything work fine - when I update / save new patient, I have a new form opened with a bunch of lab results to be entered. Some of the results belong to one table, and other to another table. patientID field, that is also visible on that 2nd form is set as it should be. However, when I try to enter ANY value in ANY field on that form - I get following warning on the status bar: "This Recordset is not updateable".
I think that this has smt to do with the fact that I actually opened 2 tables on a single form, but I might be very wrong.

Here is the code I use to open 2nd form:

```
Private Sub save_Click()
  Dim m_query As String
  m_query = "INSERT INTO labresults (patientID) VALUES (" & Me.ID & ")"
  If Me.Dirty = True Then
     Me.Dirty = False
  End If
  If DCount("patientID", "labresults", "patientID = " & Me.ID) = 0 Then
      CurrentDb.Execute m_query, dbFailOnError
  End If
  m_query = "INSERT INTO par14MO (patientID) VALUES (" & Me.ID & ")"
  If DCount("patientID", "par14MO", "patientID = " & Me.ID) = 0 Then
      CurrentDb.Execute m_query, dbFailOnError
  End If

  If CurrentProject.AllForms("labresults").IsLoaded = True Then
      Forms![labresults]![patientID] = Me.ID
      Forms![par14MO]![patientID] = Me.ID
  Else
      DoCmd.OpenForm "labresults", acNormal, , "idPAcijenta = " & Me.ID, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal, Me.ID
  End If

End Sub
```

Any ideas what's going on???

Thx a bunch!
I'm still googling and trying... I'll post my findings if I manage to sort things out!

Comment: This not the usual way of doing things in Access. Did you not find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135030/insert-a-record-into-table-in-ms-access in any way useful?

Comment: Huh... I thought that SO will inform me when answer is modified. I'm reading it now, and will comment there. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this really cannot be done :). Closing this one, and assuming this is an answer.

Edit: It was suggested to me that my last statement is not true. However, I solved things "manually", and everything is ok now. I'll go on and accept this answer in order to keep my response at a good level.

Comment: If what you're trying to do cannot be done, then you really have not explained it well, as what your questions describe is bog-standard Access.

Comment: Well, I found it on MS site: if you create a form with fields from more than one table, it's opened as read-only, since it can not be saved as a record.

Comment: It is patently untrue that a form with a recordsource that SELECTs from more than one table is automatically read-only. Whatever you read on the MS website, you've restated it incorrectly. Whether or not a multi-table SELECT is editable depends entirely on the nature of the particular SELECT statement. Also, the Jet/ACE-only DISTINCTROW can often force uneditable SELECTs into an editable state.

Comment: Ok. I needed data from two tables, and created a form using a wizard. However, as a result of my actions, and I'm still not sure which actions, the form was read-only. I removed reference to 2nd table, and used unbounded fields which I "manually" populated via VBA. That results in a form that was editable. I know this might be the wrong way, but I needed things done. Thank you for your input.